# Properly creating a SalesOrder in Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-365

I am trying to write a Dynamics 365 CRM plugin in which I want to create a new "salesorder".

I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Microsoft Dynamics CRM namespace(s)
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Samples
{
    public class OrderTest : IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            ITracingService tracingService =
                (ITracingService)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ITracingService));

            // Obtain the execution context from the service provider.
            Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext context = (Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext)
                serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.IPluginExecutionContext));

            // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
                context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                // Obtain the target entity from the input parameters.
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                if (entity.LogicalName != "salesorder")
                    return;

                try
                {
                    Entity salesorder = new Entity("salesorder");

                    salesorder["name"] = "order test";

                    IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
                    IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
                    tracingService.Trace("OrderTestPlugin: Creating the order test.");
                    Guid orderId = service.Create(salesorder);

                }
                catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                {
                    throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the OrderTest plug-in.", ex);
                }
                //</snippetFollowupPlugin3>

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    tracingService.Trace("OrderTestPlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                    throw;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that it fails creating the salesorder. The error message I get is useless. It says: `Download the details and load with Plug-in Profiler.` followed by a long token. I don't understand how to create the "salesorder" and how to get a more understandable error message.

Comment: Above code is for creating salesorder in another execution pipeline using plugin. under what message you registered this plugin step? already checking for target as salesorder? plugin profiler installed?

Comment: I registered this plugin step as follow:  Message: Create, Primary Entity: salesorder, Event Pipeline: PreValidation, Execution mode: synchronous.

I also installed plugin profiler in registration tool.

Comment: For test purposes, I am trying to programmatically create a new salesorder when a new order is created from dynamics user interface.

Comment: ok good. if you create salesorder when another Salesorder is created, this will go on loops.. for testing or learning, do it in another entity creation.Learn about plugin execution depth too..

Comment: Thanks, changing the primary entity helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have written is for creating salesorder in another execution pipeline using plugin. And you registered this plugin step to run on creation of salesorder entity record itself.

Hence this code will go on loops, to avoid that you can use depth property to stop the deadlock.

For your learning purpose, register this plugin step on some other entity & test it.